# How can I create a escape key down event handler in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I would please like to know how create a escape key down event handler.

My code:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   // some other stuff
   shapeContainer1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Esc_KeyDown);
}

public void Esc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventHandler e)
{
   // some code here
}
```

Comment: Thx Hans, I found my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code:

```
public void Esc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        // Escape is pressed here
    }
}
```

Please note that the form's `KeyPreview` property should be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

At first your event handler signature is incorrect:

```
public void Esc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

Note that ESC key is handled by controls automatically.